# Odd behavior of Where query used in foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, for-loop

I'm setting the `.Tag` property of a `ToolStripItem` created inside of a `foreach` loop using a `.Where(...)` query to get the values. The first item's `.Tag` property is correct on the first iteration of the loop, but on the second iteration, the value of the first item has changed as if I used the text from the second iteration. I'm sure I'm explaining this badly, so let's just jump to the example:

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
var values = new Dictionary<string,string[]>();

values.Add("Item1", new string[] { "Item1: Value1", "Item1: Value2", 
    "Item2: This should not end up in the Tag property" });
values.Add("Item2", new string[] { "Item2: Value1", "Item2: Value2" });

foreach (var text in values.Keys)
{
    var item = contextMenu.Items.Add(text);
    item.Tag = values[text].Where(x => x.Contains(text));
} // Set a break point here
```

First time the break occurs:
[image]

Second time the break occurs:
[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this happens this way? More importantly, how do I fix it without giving up the `.Where(...)` query?

***Note:*** This isn't my production code, I've just simplified it for this question.

Comment: Be aware that the `.Where(predicate)` extension method is implemented using lazy evaluation. This means that when you later on query that particular collection, it will evaluate the `Where` clause *then* which means that whatever is *then* in the `values[text]` collection, that fits the predicate, will be returned.

Comment: If you want to avoid this, simply consume the collection into a materialized data type there and then, such as a list or an array, using the appropriate extension method. In short, I believe your code can be fixed by modifying it to be `item.Tag = values[text].Where(x=>x.Contains(text)).ToList();`

Comment: If this is not your problem, then please post a [mcve].

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, Using `.ToList()` fixed it. Another fix I found is changing `x.Contains(text)` to `x.Contains(item.Text)`

Comment: Your loop could likely be replaced with `foreach (var kvp in values)
{ var text = kvp.Key;
    var item = contextMenu.Items.Add(text);
    item.Tag = kvp.Value.Where(x => x.Contains(text));
}` to avoid multiple hash lookups.